# how to naviagate html url to other window

Tags: iphone

Special thanks in advance for sending me answer........ 
I m the beginner in iphone development.  I was calling html page in the UISegment Controller.The url in that page html page is open in the same page. In html page i wrote the following code

```
<a href="http://google.com">www.google.com</a>
```

But it open that url in UISegment Control of WebView on same page. I want that url open in new page of safari browser in iphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a delegate to your web view.

In the delegate's class, implement `-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`. Then use UIApplication's `-openURL:` to close the app and open the page in MobileSafari.

Answer (score 1):

```
<A HREF="www.google.com" TARGET="_blank">google in a new window</A>
```